# flex tree busy cursor

Tags: apache-flex, tree, busy-cursor

i am using a tree with an array collection, i have tried to run busy cursor on expandItem but now i dont know were to stop it when the tree finishes loading children,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it :)

CursorManager.setBusyCursor() in overridden expandItem

CursorManager.removeBusyCursor(); in update complete...

```
private function onUpdateComplete(event:FlexEvent):void 
        {
            CursorManager.removeBusyCursor();
        }
```